# Split a list while keeping other columns in the data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that has three columns, and one of them contains a list:

```
A            B            C

1            Row1       [rowa,rowb,rowc]

2            Row2       [rowd,rowg,rowf]
```

I want to split only the list in column C, in different columns, but without loosing data in column A and B.

I tried this:

```
df = df['C'].apply(pd.Series)
```

However, this creates a new data frame, and it looses values in column A and B

How can I split column C into different columns, while keeping values in column A and B?

Comment: `df.assign(**df['C'].apply(pd.Series))`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the time to read this post on how to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as how to provide a [minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly

Comment: I tried this and I am getting this error: assign() keywords must be strings
Even though all keywords in col C are strings

Comment: Try updating pandas or python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pd.concat

```
df = pd.concat([df,df['C'].apply(pd.Series)],axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning to that specific column only, as shown below

```
df['D'] = df['C'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
df['E'] = df['C'].apply(lambda x: x[1])
df['F'] = df['C'].apply(lambda x: x[2])
```